# Converting hex string to hex data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsstring, nsdata

I currently have an `NSString` containing hex values.  I need to convert this `NSString` object into an `NSData` object, without changing its contents at all.

Comment: To clarify: Does your string contain hex values as an ASCII representation (e.g., { '6', 'e', '7', '5', '6', 'c', '6', 'c' }), or does it contain a sequence of bytes (e.g., { 0x6e, 0x75, 0x6c, 0x6c })?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I use this code to "parse" the debug output of an NSData object (what you get in the console if you just NSLog an NSData object) back into NSData:

```
-(NSData*) bytesFromHexString:(NSString *)aString;
{
    NSString *theString = [[aString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] componentsJoinedByString:nil];

    NSMutableData* data = [NSMutableData data];
    int idx;
    for (idx = 0; idx+2 <= theString.length; idx+=2) {
        NSRange range = NSMakeRange(idx, 2);
        NSString* hexStr = [theString substringWithRange:range];
        NSScanner* scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:hexStr];
        unsigned int intValue;
        if ([scanner scanHexInt:&intValue])
            [data appendBytes:&intValue length:1];
    }
    return data;
}
```

It's not my most robust code, but it does the job of parsing [nsdata_object description].